# SI model in Rhadoop

Tags: r, graph, igraph, rhadoop

i want to measure the diffusion of information on my graph using SI model. i define a set of initial infected nodes. i was based on this code : [Susceptible-Infected model for network diffusion](http://chengjunwang.com/en/2014/03/simulate-network-diffusion-with-R/) to develop my appropriate. but when i run my code in graph of 5000 nodes, it runs during hours. Here is my code:

```
get_infected1 = function(g, transmission_rate, diffusers){
infected=list()
Susceptible<-setdiff(V(g)$name,diffusers) 
 toss = function(freq) {
    tossing = NULL
    coins = c(1, 0)
    probabilities = c(transmission_rate, 1-transmission_rate )
    for (i in 1:freq ) tossing[i] = sample(coins, 1, rep=TRUE, prob=probabilities)
    tossing = sum(tossing)
    return (tossing)
  }

infected[[1]] = diffusers

  update_diffusers = function(diffusers){
nearest_neighbors<-data.frame()
    for (i in 1:length(diffusers)){

        L<-as.character(diffusers[i])
        Nei1 <- unique(neighbors(g,(V(g)$name == L),1))
            Nei1<-intersect(Susceptible,Nei1)
        nearest_neighbors1 = data.frame(table(unlist(Nei1)))
        nearest_neighbors = unique(rbind(nearest_neighbors,nearest_neighbors1))
                                   }
    nearest_neighbors = subset(nearest_neighbors, !(nearest_neighbors[,1]%in%diffusers))
    keep = unlist(lapply(nearest_neighbors[,2],toss))
    new = as.numeric(as.character(nearest_neighbors[,1][keep >= 1]))
      for (j in 1:length(new)){ #fill the vector
         c<-new[j]
             vec[j]<-V(g)$name[c] 
         }

    new_infected = as.vector(vec)
    diffusers = unique(c(diffusers, new_infected))
    return(diffusers)
  }

  # get infected nodes
  total_time = 1
  node_number=vcount(g)
  while(length(Susceptible) > 0){
    infected[[total_time+1]] = sort(update_diffusers(infected[[total_time]]))
    Susceptible<-setdiff(Susceptible, infected[[total_time+1]])
    total_time = total_time + 1
    }
  # return the infected nodes list
  return(infected)
}
```

Each node of initial infected nodes infects his neighbors with some probability, so as output we get the list of infected nodes in each step.

I want to adjust this code to run on RHadoop system. but i am newbie in RHadoop. i don't know where exactly i should modify, and how could i introduce my graph on hadoop?? please any suggestions?